Spring boot can't make https request using public IP but a general python server works
I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot server and I have a problem with making requests from one machine to another using the public ip. Both are running windows.
I first tried with the embedded tomcat server but requests don't work and also telnet <public ip> 443 returns timeout.
Both machines have inbound and outbound rules for port 443.
Another thing I tried just to make sure it's not a firewall issue was creating the most basic python server on 443 like so:
python3 -m http.server 443
Running this server, it will allow me to actually make a request to the public IP and although it will show errors on the server side, at least I see the request passing.
Also telnet with port 443 also connects with the python server, so the firewall rule seems to be working and it's not blocking the connection.
So the problem is only when I use the spring boot server.
I have set in the application.yml
server:
  port: 443

I have also tried setting the address as well:
server:
  port: 443
  address: <public ip>

I also tried running the jar with -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true as I found on stackoverflow suggested in other questions.
I tried switching to using the embedded jetty but that one also didn't work.
I would prefer to use the embedded tomcat but at this point I suspected that the problem might be from the fact that I was trying to run the JAR with the embedded tomcat, so I followed the Official documentation on traditional deployment and deployed a war in tomcat and configured the server.xml with the example from their documentations and I added connectors as such:
<Connector address="<public ip>" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />

<Connector address="<public ip>" port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                     certificateKeystorePassword="changeit" type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

I'm not sure what else to do, I exhausted all the articles and all the stack overflow posts regarding this so I'm now writing this one. Am I the only one who has this problem?
Let me know if there are any other details I can add to the post.

If your python3 runs as admin it may be authorized to open port 443 while the Java process is not, try 8443 to confirm.
